# Resize an image to take up all of a <div>

Tags: html, css

How can I constrain an image in a container so that the whole container is filled with as much as the image as possible?

For example (I do not know what size that images will be, this is just an example) - If I have an image container of 100x100 and an image of 600x400, the following conditions would need to be met.

- The image should be displayed at 150x100
- The image should be centred in the container
- The overflow of the image (25px left and right in this example) should be hidden.

***Please note*** - some images will be of greater height than width, so any solution needs to work with images of all sizes, centreing both horizontally and vertically.

Sadly, any solution also has to work with IE9 (as that is the browser that the owners of the intranet I am working on use), so HTML5/CSS3 solutions will not work.

Here are a couple of visual examples -

[image: Example of image display 1]
[image: Example of image display 2]

I've tried various CSS styles -

- If I nest the `<img>` inside of a `<div>` container then the image
- If I absolutly place the `<img>` over a `<div>` then I am unable to centre it vertically if it is wider than tall (I.e. 600x400).

Any suggestions would be gratefully received.

Comment: There's a great article on css-tricks here http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/ that explains how to do full page images, you can use the same principle with your div

Comment: You need javascript to work that out...

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan 150 = 600/4 rescaling image to have a display height of 100px

Comment: I worked on a similar problem a few years ago and the much of it could be done with CSS2.  However, the CSS depended on the aspect ratio of the image and I had to use JavaScript to toggle the correct CSS rule to use depending on the aspect ratio of the image, which could only be determined by JavaScript/jQuery.  The only alternative would be if you could send the image dimensions to the page based on server-side scripting.  Please extend comments in the original post, thank you.

Comment: Have tried use %(percentege) instead of px(pixels unit) on image width?

Comment: @Cold - I don't know what size the images will be, therefore I don't know what percentage of the image to show. Thanks.

Comment: If you use 100%, for example on with, regardless you image size, it will make you image fill all `div` (all `width` in this case). Have you tried see @Harsukh Makwana answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned it has to work with IE9: `background-size: cover` will do just that. You just can't use the image itself as an img element but have to assign it as a background image to the container.

I made a jsfiddle for you [here](http://jsfiddle.net/1n5t0qqu/)

Comment: This works, however it's not ideal. I'm not opposed to inline styling, but I'd like to find a better way if possible, so will continue the hunt...

Comment: yeah, same here. The problem is: there isn't any (that i have found or made), at least not a pure-css implementation. Might you however find a solution for it... shoot me a message, i'm curious to find out how :-)

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly the result you're looking for but with only CSS you could try this demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/AotBk

Relevant CSS code

```
.wrapper {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  border: 2px dashed #ccc;
}

.wrapper img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%); 
}
```

I've used 2D translation, which is [supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d) even on `IE9`

---

Screenshot of resulting effect with three images (600x400, 300x600 and 50x50) into a 100x100 wrapper

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it's not quite what I need. A very useful fall back if required though.

Answer (score -1):

Try it:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <style>
        .container{
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
        }
        .container img{
            max-width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <img src="img/image.jpg"> <!-- here image width 600*400 -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, but all that does is fit the image in to the container while keeping it's aspect ratio. Not what I'm looking for I'm afraid.